# Non-linear regression models in PostgreSQL using R

Tags: postgresql, r, statistics, data-analysis

#### Background

I have climate data (temperature, precipitation, snow depth) for all of Canada between 1900 and 2009. I have written a basic website and the simplest page allows users to choose category and city. They then get back a very simple report (without the parameters and calculations section):

[image]

The primary purpose of the web application is to provide a simple user interface so that the general public can explore the data in meaningful ways. (A list of numbers is not meaningful to the general public, nor is a website that provides [too many inputs](http://www7.ncdc.noaa.gov/CDO/CDODivisionalSelect.jsp).) The secondary purpose of the application is to provide climatologists and other scientists with deeper ways to view the data. (Using too many inputs, of course.)

#### Tool Set

The database is PostgreSQL with R (mostly) installed. The reports are written using iReport and generated using JasperReports.

#### Poor Model Choice

Currently, a linear regression model is applied against annual averages of daily data. The linear regression model is calculated within a PostgreSQL function as follows:

```
SELECT 
  regr_slope( amount, year_taken ),
  regr_intercept( amount, year_taken ),
  corr( amount, year_taken )
FROM
  temp_regression
INTO STRICT slope, intercept, correlation;
```

The results are returned to JasperReports using:

```
SELECT
  year_taken,
  amount,
  year_taken * slope + intercept,
  slope,
  intercept,
  correlation,
  total_measurements
INTO result;
```

JasperReports calls into PostgreSQL using the following parameterized analysis function:

```
SELECT
  year_taken,
  amount,
  measurements,
  regression_line,
  slope,
  intercept,
  correlation,
  total_measurements,
  execute_time
FROM
  climate.analysis(
    $P{CityId},
    $P{Elevation1},
    $P{Elevation2},
    $P{Radius},
    $P{CategoryId},
    $P{Year1},
    $P{Year2}
  )
ORDER BY year_taken
```

This is not an optimal solution because it gives the false impression that the climate is changing at a slow, but steady rate.

#### Questions

Using functions that take two parameters (e.g., year [X] and amount [Y]), such as PostgreSQL's `regr_slope`:

- What is a better regression model to apply?
- What CPAN-R packages provide such models? (Installable, ideally, using `apt-get`.)
- How can the R functions be called within a PostgreSQL function?

If no such functions exist:

- What parameters should I try to obtain for functions that will produce the desired fit?
- How would you recommend showing the best fit curve?

Keep in mind that this is a web app for use by the general public. If the only way to analyse the data is from an R shell, then the purpose has been defeated. (I know this is not the case for most R functions I have looked at so far.)

Thank you!

Comment: Linear regression is based on an assumption of independence. Sometimes this assumption doesn't hold, if the data are collected over time (or space) and the observations are related. Time Series Analysis is a specialized field of statistics that deals with this type of problem. BUT, there are two extensions of regression methods to situations where the time series is of the first-order autoregressive type. Both are described in detail on ch.15 here http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Sleuth-Course-Methods-Analysis/dp/0534386709/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1275031609&sr=8-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The awesome [pl/r](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/) package allows you to run R inside PostgreSQL as a procedural language.  There are some gotchas because R likes to think about data in terms of vectors which is not what a RDBMS does. It is still a very useful package as it gives you *R inside of PostgreSQL* saving you some of the roundtrips of your architecture.

And [pl/r](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/) is `apt-get`-able for you as it has been part of Debian / Ubuntu for a while. Start with `apt-cache show postgresql-8.4-plr` (that is on testing, other versions/flavours have it too).

As for the appropriate modeling: that is a whole different ballgame. `loess` is a fair suggestion for something non-parametric, and you probably also want some sort of dynamic model, either ARMA/ARIMA or lagged regression.  The choice of modeling is pretty critical given how politicized the topic is.

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. I should have mentioned I already installed PL/R. (It didn't install out-of-the-box due to library path issues with the amd64 package for 8.4.) I'll look into ARMA/ARIMA, lagged regression, and LOESS. I was more wondering what R packages to install on top of PL/R.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think autoregression is what you want.  Non-linear isn't what you want either because the implies discontinuous data.  You have continuous data, it just may not be a straight line.  If you're just visualizing, and especially if you don't know what the shape is supposed to be then loess is what you want.

It's easy to also get a confidence interval band around the line if you just plot the data with ggplot2.

```
qplot(x, y, data = df, geom = 'point') + stat_smooth()
```

That will make a nice plot.

If you want to a simpler graph in straight R.

```
plot(x, y)
lines(loess.smooth(x,y))
```

Answer (score 1):

May I propose a different solution? Just use PostgreSQL to pull the data, feed it into some R script and finally show the results. The R script may be as complicated as you want as long as the user doesn't have to deal with it.

You may want to have a look at [rapache](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rapache/), an Apache module that allows running R scripts in a webpage.
A couple of videos illustrating its use:

- [Hello world application](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/02/r-web-application-hello-world-using-rapache-7min-video-tutorial/)
- [Jeffrey Horner's presentation of RApache + links to working apps](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2010/01/how-to-integrate-r-into-webbased-applications-video.html?cid=6a010534b1db25970b012876fc16d9970c)

In particular check how the [San Francisco Estuary Institue Web Query Tool](http://eis.sfei.org/wqt/) allows the user to interact with the parameters.

As for the regression, I'm not an expert, so I may be saying something extremely stupid... but wouldn't something like a LOESS regression be OK for this?

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: of course, I understand it's not so easy to reimplement everything, I wasn't sure at what point you were with the project of course :)

Anyway my idea of just pulling the data in PostgreSQL and feed them into R for the regression is still applicable, isn't it? Here's a page with some LOESS examples with R http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Statistics/loess.htm

Comment: 17 days to migrate from MySQL to Postgresql? Yeebus. I like Pg better to, but R would have been very happy to read from MySQL too.  And as others have said, you don't need Jasper.  But if that is what you know, go for it.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: I'm definitely not gonna downvote it for that, although I think you can easily do a graph like that in R with a one-liner :) Still, I do not understand why you think the user would have to interact with R. You would have a bunch of R functions that generate one graph or another, the user would not have to interact at all with it. Using RApache you would have been able to use PHP to pull raw data from your DB, send that raw data to R and then have it process it and return it to the PHP script (see the 3rd link in my answer).